# Installing two identical Linux systems with full disk encryption alongside each other - second one overwrites EFI entries

Tags: linux, multi-boot, grub, uefi, luks

Disclaimer: I've seen a few similar posts online, answers to which suggested that reinstalling grub might help. I tried it (see below), but for me the issue is still unresolved.

I wanted to set up two Debian 11 systems, each in a separate LUKS container. After the second installation I realized that **no new boot options appeared in boot menu**, i.e. the second installation must have overwritten entries created by the first one (by default those options had been called: *Debian* for booting via *shim* (Secure Boot) and *debian* for booting straight via *grub* (no Secure Boot)).

After giving it a thought, it made sense - since both installs were Debian, their EFI entries (**i.e. their labels in boot menu, available under F11 at PC boot**) must have had the exact same names. Moreover, since the first system had been installed on a fully encrypted parition, the second installer had no way of knowning about it, so it just went ahead and installed grub anew, overwriting all EFI-related configuration.

As a result the first system is unbootable.

I tried booting into the second system and chrooting into the first one. From there I reinstalled grub, choosing a name (`--bootloader-id`) different from the default ones (i.e *Debian* and *debian*):

`grub-install --target=x86_64-efi --efi-directory=/boot/efi --bootloader-id=Debian1`

This partially helped - *Debian1* boot entry was added and `/boot/efi/EFI/Debian1` directory was created. What is more, to my limited knowledge, everything seems in order - both EFI directories contain their own grub.cfg files that point to the correct encrypted volume - I manually checked that. Despite all that, choosing *Debian1* at boot time still loads the second, newer system.

I would appreciate help getting the two systems to be normally bootable.

---

Update:

1. I found some information about bootloader chainloading/dual booting two Linux OSes at [Gentoo Wiki](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/GRUB2/Chainloading#Another_bootloader) and [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/GRUB#GNU/Linux).
   This (chainloading another grub instance via custom grub menu entry) could be viewed as a solution, but would be far from what I'm looking for, because even if chainloading encrypted grub worked (I did not try it yet), it would require both passwords to get to the inner
   grub.
2. After playing around for a little while, I noticed that reinstalling grub results in a bootable system **only when I don't specify a custom** `--bootloader-id`, otherwise I get dropped to the grub console. What could be the reason behind this?

---

Edits:

1. Expanded the paragraph on what I think happened after second installation
2. Added information about custom menu entries on Arch and Gentoo Wiki pages.
3. Added information about `--bootloader-id` option

Comment: have you tried F12 or whatever key for boot menu to see if there are two Debian entries (and try to run each from this menu)?

Comment: There were two, but only because a single Debian install creates two by default. One for shim (Secure Boot) and one for grub (no Secure Boot). With that said, I've written that _After the second installation I realized that **no new boot options appeared in boot menu**_, ergo at any given moment there were only options corresponding to one of the two installations.

I have edited the question to (among other things) make this more clear.

Comment: [this](https://www.tangibleabstraction.com/2020/05/27/how-to-boot-multiple-ubuntu-installs-with-efi/)?

Comment: Not exactly. This tutorial speaks of chainloading a bootloader, which I also read about and mentioned that in the question (after edits), but it's not really what I'm looking for - it would either require not encrypting /boot partition(s) or chainloading an encrypted bootloader from an encrypted bootloader, resulting in 2 password prompts (if it's even doable, I haven't tried it)